# Will it be haram to earn money by lying while negotiating a (buying) deal

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, money, business, lying

I know it's haram to lie. My question is more complicated than just lying to earn money. What if I want to see if the other person is giving me a reasonable price and to do that I lie that I am getting the same deal in less. For example what if I tell the supplier that I am getting something he's supplying for 2 rupee/kg at the rate of 1 rupee/kg just to negotiate? I know it'll be a sin to lie but will the money earned through that deal be haram?